# Saving a key from a dictionary without value

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

I am representing a weighted graph as a dictionary where the key represents a vertex and the following lists represent the edges incident on the vertex (first number weight of edge and second number adjacent vertex):

```
wGraph = { 1 : [[2, 2],[3, 4],[3, 3]],
       3 : [[3, 2],[5, 4],[7, 5]],
       2 : [[2, 1],[4, 4],[3, 6]],
       4 : [[3, 1],[4, 2],[1, 6],[5, 3]],
       6 : [[3, 2],[1, 4],[8, 5]],
       5 : [[7, 3],[8, 6],[9, 7]],
       7 : [9, 5]}
```

I would like to save a random key without its value from the dictionary to a list called visited.

```
random_num = random.randrange(len(wGraph))

visited = []
```

How can I get the key from the dictionary according to the random number?

Comment: Are the keys always just numbers 1...max? Then the answer would just be `randon_num + 1`.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that too, but I would prefer a chice where the key could be founded even though the keys would not be in a numeric order, or when the keys are for example letters.

Answer (score 3):

To make a random choice from some values, use `random.choice`. You want to choose from the keys of the dictionary, so that's exactly what you pass in:

```
random.choice(wGraph.keys())
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is so inefficient. Unless you want to mess with the C structures directly, Python provides no way to pick a random key without materializing a list of keys.

Comment: @user2357112 python is oss so feel free to submit a patch.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: There isn't really a good way to design the functionality that fits with Python's design philosophy, though. If you just provide a "get random key" function, it misses a lot of similar use cases, such as drawing random samples (particularly for large samples where rejection sampling is inefficient). If you provide more direct access to the hash table, you're exposing implementation details pretty hard, and it's an awkward interface to work with. Any attempt to provide efficient random key selection also restricts the design decisions available to other Python...

Comment: implementations, since you need something like open addressing or PyPy's dense key array to support it; separate chaining would make it difficult. If you really need frequent, efficient random key selection, it's probably best to maintain a list of keys yourself. It just kind of bugs me that the performance opportunity is there, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to take it.

Comment: When I try to use it in python 3 it gives me: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the details -- how many keys do you have, are they always numbers 1...max, do you want to revisit keys you've already visited before, are graph nodes added over time or do they stay constant, will you eventually visit all keys or only a small percentage of them, and so on.

One idea: if your keys are always numbered sequentially as in your example, you can just use `random_num + 1`. You already know they are the keys of the dict and you don't have to construct anything special.

Another option is to randomize the key list just once:

```
>>> keys_to_visit = wGraph.keys()
>>> keys_to_visit.shuffle()
>>> first_key_to_visit = keys_to_visit.pop()
```

And just keep calling .pop() whenever you need a new one. This only works if you don't want to revisit nodes and the node list is constant.

Comment: When I try to use the shuffle it gives me: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: @Leero11: Oops, I'm too used to Python 2. In Python 3 you need to turn the keys iterator into a list first (`keys_to_visit = list(wGraph.keys())`).

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

visited = []

def random_key():
    wGraph = {1: [[2, 2], [3, 4], [3, 3]],
              3: [[3, 2], [5, 4], [7, 5]],
              2: [[2, 1], [4, 4], [3, 6]],
              4: [[3, 1], [4, 2], [1, 6], [5, 3]],
              6: [[3, 2], [1, 4], [8, 5]],
              5: [[7, 3], [8, 6], [9, 7]],
              7: [9, 5]}

    random_key = random.choice(wGraph.keys())

    if random_key not in visited:
        visited.append(random_key)
    print visited


for e in range(7):
    random_key()
```